# Display a List of used Table and Column

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

Goal:
Display detailed information if database A use database B:s table and its column. if yes, the list will display what is the name of the database B:s table and column that is being used in database A.

Purpose:
Database A has about 200 View and 400 tables and database B has about 154 View and 165 tables and I don't wanna review each table and view in order to locate what table and column it use from database B. The main purpose is to reduce the time.

Problem:
I do not know how to do it?

Information:
*I'm using SQL server 2008 R2

Answer (score 2):

The [catalog view `sys.sql_expression_dependencies`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/bb677315(v=sql.105)) gets you close. For example:

```
SELECT 
  [A view] = s.name + '.' + v.name, 'references',
  [B object] = d.referenced_database_name + '.' 
             + d.referenced_schema_name + '.' 
             + d.referenced_entity_name
FROM DatabaseA.sys.views AS v
INNER JOIN DatabaseA.sys.schemas AS s
ON v.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
INNER JOIN DatabaseA.sys.sql_expression_dependencies AS d
ON v.[object_id] = d.[referencing_id]
WHERE d.referenced_database_name = N'DatabaseB';
```

It does not provide column names, however.

Unfortunately other catalog views like [`sql_dependencies`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms174402(v=sql.105)) are unreliable for this kind of thing, since they don't follow dependencies outside the scope of the current database. And it's deprecated anyway. However there are more reliable views, like [`sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/bb677185(v=sql.105)):

```
SELECT 
  [A view] = s.name + '.' + v.name, 'references',
  [B column] = r.referenced_database_name + '.'
             + r.referenced_schema_name + '.'
             + r.referenced_entity_name + '.'
             + r.referenced_minor_name         
FROM DatabaseA.sys.views AS v
INNER JOIN DatabaseA.sys.schemas AS s
ON v.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
CROSS APPLY DatabaseA.sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities
(
  QUOTENAME(s.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(v.name), N'OBJECT'
) AS r
WHERE r.referenced_minor_id > 0
AND r.referenced_database_name = N'DatabaseB';
```

Some other links that might help:

- [Understanding SQL Dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms345449(v=sql.105))
- [Troubleshooting SQL Dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/cc879246(v=sql.105))

Also understand that dependencies are hard, they've changed the approach several times since SQL Server 2000, and [we've had a long history of employing workarounds to ensure that the information is current and consistent](https://sqlblog.org/2008/09/09/keeping-sysdepends-up-to-date-in-sql-server-2008) (but still tend to fail on a regular basis).